# ValueError in Bayesianoptimization

Tags: optimization, neural-network, hyperparameters

I am trying Bayesian optimization for the first time for neural network and ran into this error:

> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64').

I checked my input data, I don't have any nan or infinite values.

The code for HP tuning is

```
def nn_cl_bo(neurons, activation, optimizer, learning_rate, batch_size, layers1, layers2, normalization, dropout, dropout_rate, epochs):
    optimizerL = ['Adam', 'RMSprop']
    optimizerD= {'Adam':Adam(lr=learning_rate), 'RMSprop':RMSprop(lr=learning_rate)}
    
    activationL = ['linear','relu', 'tanh']
    optimizer = optimizerD[optimizerL[round(optimizer)]]
    neurons = round(neurons)
    activation = activationL[round(activation)]
    batch_size = round(batch_size)
    epochs = round(epochs)
    def nn_cl_fun():
        #opt = Adam(lr = learning_rate)
        nn = Sequential()
        nn.add(SimpleRNN(neurons, input_shape=(25,1), activation=activation))
        nn.add(Dense(neurons, activation=activation))
        if normalization > 0.5:
            nn.add(BatchNormalization())
        for i in range(layers1):
            nn.add(Dense(neurons, activation=activation))
        if dropout > 0.5:
            nn.add(Dropout(dropout_rate, seed=123))
        for i in range(layers2):
            nn.add(Dense(neurons, activation=activation))
        #nn.add(Dropout(0.2))
        nn.add(Dense(neurons, activation=activation))
        nn.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
        nn.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'])
        return nn
    
    es = EarlyStopping(monitor='mse', mode='min', verbose=0)
    nn = KerasRegressor(build_fn=nn_cl_fun, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=0)
    kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=123)
    score = cross_val_score(nn, train_x, train_y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=kf, fit_params={'callbacks':[es]}).mean()
    return score

# Set parameters
params_nn ={'neurons': (10, 100),
            'activation':(0, 2),
            'optimizer':(0,1),
            'learning_rate':(0.01, 1),
            'batch_size':(200, 500),
            'layers1':(1,3),
            'layers2':(1,3),
            'normalization':(0,1),
            'dropout':(0,1),
            'dropout_rate':(0,0.3),
            'epochs':(20, 50)}

# Run Bayesian Optimization
nn_bo = BayesianOptimization(nn_cl_bo, params_nn)
nn_bo.maximize(init_points=25, n_iter=4)
```

However the output when I run the above code is as below. The target column shows as nan. Not sure if this is the reason of the ValueError. Can anyone help me understand what is this target column or why I am getting nan in here?

```
|   iter    |  target   | activa... | batch_... |  dropout  | dropou... |  epochs   |  layers1  |  layers2  | learni... |  neurons  | normal... | optimizer |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1        |  nan      |  1.224    |  250.7    |  0.4361   |  0.2308   |  28.86    |  1.298    |  1.045    |  0.426    |  31.48    |  0.3377   |  0.9907   |
|  2        |  nan      |  0.4755   |  224.4    |  0.6696   |  0.1864   |  28.23    |  1.932    |  1.237    |  0.08322  |  91.07    |  0.794    |  0.8406   |
|  3        |  nan      |  1.63     |  497.3    |  0.5773   |  0.2441   |  32.64    |  1.055    |  1.908    |  0.1143   |  83.55    |  0.6977   |  0.5653   |
....
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, below snippets solve the problem

```
score = cross_val_score(nn, train_x, train_y, scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv=kf, fit_params={'callbacks':[es]})

score=np.nan_to_num(score)

score=score.mean()

return score
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).